# Multiple Update statements in one stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

Is it possible to have more than one update statement in a single stored procedure updating multiple tables, I seem to be having problems with the parameters in the second update, the code is as follows.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUpdateUserProfile]
 @userID int,
 @UserName varchar(50),
 @FirstName varchar(50),
 @MiddleName varchar(50),
 @LastName varchar(50),
 @email varchar(50),
 @answer varchar(50),
 @QuestionID int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    UPDATE dbo.USERS 
        SET userName = @userID, 
        FIRSTNAME = @FirstName, 
        MIDDLENAME = @MiddleName, 
        SURNAME = @LastName,
        EMAILADDRESS = @email
        WHERE USERID = @userID;

    UPDATE dbo.USERPASSWORDS
    SET Answer = @answer, 
    QuestionID = @QuestionID 
    WHERE USERID = @userID;
END
```

Comment: The short answer is **YES**, you can have multiple UPDATES and queries in a stored procedure. Now, the reason why your second UPDATE is not working is not clear. What exactly is not working? Is it updating the incorrect rows or no rows? With incorrect values possibly? Or does it throw a foreign key constraint error? Please provide more details about the actual problem.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! It would really be helpful to us and to your question if you include some details regarding the problem you are encountering. _...I seem to be having problems with the parameters..._ is too broad. Do you get any errors? Does it save the wrong data? Kindly be inclusive of those details here and in your future posts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to have more than one update statement in a single stored procedure. What you can do is you have to use prepared statements for each update query and there you go !

Let me show you with example :

```
 SET @sql = CONCAT('UPDATE dbo.USERS SET userName = @userID, FIRSTNAME = @FirstName, MIDDLENAME = @MiddleName, SURNAME = @LastName, EMAILADDRESS = @email  WHERE USERID = @userID;');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Why you do this approach, instead of a ```create or replace proc```?... Moreover, you don't desribe multiple update commands but only one is exhibited in your solution.